# Rails assign two attributes with one form item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have an object with attributes `first_team_name` and `second_team_name`, and a list that has pairs of `[team1, team2]` values.

I would like to be able to have it so when I select an object in the form, it assigns `team1` to `first_team_name` and `team2` to `second_team_name`, but I have no idea how to split those values accordingly.

Is there anyway to split the values of my collection and put them to two different attributes of my object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define 2 functions in your model

```
def team_names
  return "#{first_team_name},#{second_team_name}"
end

def team_names=(values)
  self.first_team_name, self.last_team_name = values.split(',')
end
```

Warnings

- your select values must be like `'toto,titi'`.
- Choose an other separator if team name can include commas.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible by parsing the arguments in the controller and then assigning them to whichever object you want. I don't know if this is best practice, though. You will need to modify the `update` method of the Controller.